# Draw square box using the coordinates on image in android(JAVA)

Tags: java, kotlin

I have some coordinates which is coming from the backend. I need to draw some rectangles or squares according to the coordinates on image in the (JAVA) android app. The rectangles or squares should be clickable [you can see the coordinates in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sotxO.png)

> public class DrawView extends View {
> Paint paint = new Paint();
>
> ```
> private void init() {
>     paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
> }
>
> public DrawView(Context context) {
>     super(context);
>     init();
> }
>
> public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>     super(context, attrs);
>     init();
> }
>
> public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
>     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
>     init();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
>     canvas.drawRoundRect(150,150,300,300,10,10,paint);
>     canvas.drawRect(300, 300, 600, 600,paint);
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use a `Canvas` to draw rectangles on a bitmap, but if you want to be able to touch parts of the image and make it react depending on what you've drawn there, you'll probably need to write a custom view: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components

Comment: Why do you need a heigth and a width values if you already have the top-left and the bottom-right corners?